# Issues converting JS object to query string

Tags: javascript

I need to convert and JS object to query string and this object can wrap nested objects, like this:

```
 var item = {
        field1: 100,
        field2: 200,
        field3: [ 1,2,3 ],
        field4: {
            field5: 300,
            field6: 'Quad',
            field7: [ 4,5,6]
        }
    };
```

To convert this object I'm using this function

```
var serialize2 = function(obj, prefix) {
        var str = [], p;
        for (p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
                str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
                    serialize2(v, k) :
                encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
            }
        }
        return str.join("&");
    };
```

And once converted my query string looks like this

> field4[field5]=300&field4[field6]=Quad

instead of

> field4.field5=300&field4.field6=Quad

And then my Java Spring Application can't bind this children object

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your convert function:

```
var serialize2 = function(obj, prefix) {
    var str = [], p;
    for (p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            var k;
            if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
                k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
            } else {
                k = prefix ? prefix + "." + p : p, v = obj[p];
            }
            str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
                serialize2(v, k) :
            encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
    }
    return str.join("&");
};
```

Comment: It fixes my issue with nested objects but broke my array:

"field1=100
&field2=200
&field3.0=1
&field3.1=2
&field3.2=3
&field4.field5=300
&field4.field6=Quad
&field4.field7.0=4
&field4.field7.1=5
&field4.field7.2=6"

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you used arrays as well. Changed my answer so it should work with how you're doing things.

Answer (score 1):

```
  function generateQueryParam(parameterMap) {
        var queryString = '';
        var _keys = Object.keys(parameterMap);

        _keys.forEach(mapResolver);

        function mapResolver(k, i) {
            var value = parameterMap[k];
            if (i < _keys.length-1) {
                queryString += k + '=' + value + '&';
            } else {
                queryString += k + '=' + value;
            }
        }
        return queryString;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: FYI : this only do convert plain js object to query string.If you need to resolve for nested objects go with some recursive strategy

Comment: Could you explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: this screenshot will explain .It will convert js object to a Query string @Anzeo